# Duplicating browsers or contacts list fling behavior using Scroller.fling with an infinite grid

Tags: android, algorithm, physics

Imagine a grid (implemented using a canvas) that is infinite to the right and bottom, but has a bound on left and top. I want to be able to scroll this grid using fling gestures. I implemented this using the `GestureDetector` and `Scroller` classes like below. While this is mostly acceptable and looks good, the distance and speed of the scrolling is rather short / slow when doing a strong fling.

This is good when doing a less powerful fling, for example like you would do when you only wanted to scroll your contacts list or browser a little. For a fling that would scroll your contacts list a lot however, this method only scrolls my grid a little more than the previous one does.

I'm not sure what to set the `minX/maxX/minY/maxY` parameters to in order to achieve those effects, or what else to change. The value I chose so far is a good compromise for my purposes: it never scrolls too much or too fast, but it does scroll too little and too slow for strong flings.

How can I achieve a similar fling behavior to the contacts list (I'm thinking about the ICS / JB one, but I think all of them behave roughly the same in this regard) and browsers in my infinite grid?

**Relevant code listing:**

```
private int mFlingPrevX, mFlingPrevY;
private void moveSurface() {
    if (mFlinger.computeScrollOffset()) {

        mScroll.x = -mFlinger.getCurrX() + mFlingPrevX;
        mScroll.y = -mFlinger.getCurrY() + mFlingPrevY;

        mFlingPrevX = mFlinger.getCurrX();
        mFlingPrevY = mFlinger.getCurrY();

        invalidate();

        post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                moveSurface();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(final MotionEvent motionEvent1, final MotionEvent motionEvent2, final float velocityX, final float velocityY) {

    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(mContext);
    if (Math.abs(velocityX) < config.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity() || Math.abs(velocityY) < config.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity()) {
        return true;
    }

    mFlinger = new Scroller(mContext);

    mFlingPrevX = getScrollX();
    mFlingPrevY = getScrollY();

    // 380 is a magic number that works OK, but it doesn't do what I'm asking here
    int distance = (int)(GameGlobals.getScreenDensityFactor(mContext) * 380); 
    mFlinger.fling(mFlingPrevX, mFlingPrevY, -(int)velocityX, -(int)velocityY, -distance, distance, -distance, distance);

    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            moveSurface();
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Comment: How about custom scroller physics ? I.e deceleration(d) inversely proportional to initial velocity (vi). Using `distance = vi + 1/2(d)(t^2)`

Comment: @wingman - I'm not sure I follow. Since you have `t` in there, which is time I'm guessing, am I supposed to put that in my `moveSurface` method? In that case, where do I get `d` from and how do I use `distance`? If I'm supposed to put that in my `onFling` method, what is `t`?

Comment: Never mind, Physics part is already implemented in `Scroller` class,  It has a `fling()` method, where you can start your fling, and  useful method here is: `setFriction()` , so before flinging, the lower you set friction, farther the scroll moves. `Scroller` class also takes an interpolator, the class `DecelerateInterpolator` fits the bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was easier than expected. The first two parameters actually give information about where the fling started and where it ended, so we can find the distance variable based on that.

```
float dx = motionEvent1.getRawX() - motionEvent2.getRawX();
float dy = motionEvent1.getRawY() - motionEvent2.getRawY();
int distance = 3 * (int)Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
mFlinger.fling(mFlingPrevX, mFlingPrevY, -(int)velocityX, -(int)velocityY, 
               -distance, distance, -distance, distance);
```

I like this one best so far, but obviously it can be changed to anything you like.